# Express res.redirect() not redirecting the browser URL when called from a frontend fetch() request

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, react-router

I have seemed to run into an issue I have not come across yet. I have an API route in the backend that when called, will redirect the browser URL to `/signin` via `res.redirect('/signin')` (or so I thought). With React Router, this URL will then trigger the rendering of a 'log back in' component. This essentially is to handle the expiration of a JWT token, and deals with sending the user back to a log in page when their token expires.

The main `Dashboard` component receives a JWT token from the backend that is generated for the user when they log in. This JWT token is used for the frontend to access protected API routes. The JWT token is stored into `localStorage` with an expiration time. Once the token expires, it shows up as undefined. When the `Dashboard` component re-mounts, it always checks in localStorage to make sure it has a valid JWT token and that is not undefined.

When the JWT token has expired, and shows as `undefined`, the component makes a call to a backend route that handles redirecting the user back to a URL that allows them to log back in with a freshly generated JWT token.

Finally, here is some code *(code that does not pertain to this has be redacted for brevity)*.

***Frontend call to the backend `logout` route:*** I make this call in componentDidUpdate() because every time my Redux store is updated, this re-renders the component, checking again for a valid token, and since it does not fire on the initial component mount, it gives the component time to store the token.

```
componentDidUpdate() {
const currentkey = localStorage.getItem('userToken');

    if(currentkey === 'undefined'){
       fetch('/account/logout', {
          method: 'GET'
       })
       .catch(err => {
          console.log(err)
       })
    }
 }
```

***Here is the backend `logout` route:*** I have tried to use `res.redirect('/signin')` to no avail here. It does not change the URL when called. It doesn't throw an error or anything. It is just seemingly ignored. When I add a `console.log()` to it, I can see that the frontend `fetch()` definitely calls to it, and triggers the `console.log()`, so I at least know that it is being called from the frontend. Postman also confirms the route is reachable.

```
 app.get('/account/logout', (req, res) => {
     res.redirect('/signin');
     console.log('logout route called');
 });
```

The thing that confuses me is that my entire sign up/in system uses `res.redirect()` in those specific routes, and everything works just fine. I have never had this problem where the URL doesn't change.

Should I be redirecting the user this way? Can I even use a `fetch()` request like that? As I have mentioned, I am using React Router so I would also like to ask if there is a way to redirect the browser URL using this rather that handling it in the backend.

Thanks in advance for reading and any insight!

Comment: An ajax call made from the browser's Javascript with `fetch()` or `XMLHttpRequest` just returns the http response and let's your Javascript process it.  It doesn't cause the browser page to change in any way.  If you want the page to change, you have to read that response and then change the page yourself in the browser Javascript.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Very insightful.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make the redirection client side instead of the server side. You can use something from React Router like `return <Redirect to='/somewhere'/>;` after checking for example `this.state.redirect`.

Comment: Alright I will look into that tomorrow. Thanks for the help!